# How would I loop through this array to total/calculate scores

Tags: vb.net

I have an array of scores coming out of a text file and i'm trying to loop through them to add up all the scores.  The scores are in String right now so I need help to convert them to integers and use a loop to add them all up.

The scores are that need to be converted and added are p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,exam1,exam2

Here is my code now.  Any help would be appreciated; Thanks!

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Dim textFile As String

Private Sub btnSelect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    textFile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim data() As String = File.ReadAllLines(textFile)


    Dim myArray As String = data(0)
    Dim studentInfo() = myArray.Split(","c)

    Dim studentname As String = studentInfo(0)
    Dim subject As String = studentInfo(1)
    Dim semester As String = studentInfo(2)
    Dim photo As String = studentInfo(3)
    Dim p1 As String = studentInfo(4)
    Dim p2 As String = studentInfo(5)
    Dim p3 As String = studentInfo(6)
    Dim p4 As String = studentInfo(7)
    Dim p5 As String = studentInfo(8)
    Dim p6 As String = studentInfo(9)
    Dim exam1 As String = studentInfo(10)
    Dim exam2 As String = studentInfo(11)


    lblName.Text = studentname
    lblSubject.Text = subject
    lblSemester.Text = semester
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(photo)
    lblP1.Text = p1
    lblP2.Text = p2
    lblP3.Text = p3
    lblP4.Text = p4
    lblP5.Text = p5
    lblP6.Text = p6
    lblExam1.Text = exam1
    lblExam2.Text = exam2
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: p1, p2... are not an array they are declared as string variables which get some data from an array.  Just add up their values if you need a total.

Comment: They are part of the array aren't they?   I just need to add them basically but Im having trouble finding the right code to do that.  Would it be something like lblGrade = CInt(p1 + p2 + etc. etc.) ?

Comment: for each line as string in data
...
next

Comment: `Dim p1 As String` means it is a simple string variable. The same string value still resides at `StudentInfo(4)`.  Unless this is a homework assignment where you have the use an array, I'd store the **values** I have to work with in a List.  I emphasize values because "23" is not the same as 23.

Comment: I might start by *actually* using arrays and other typed structures .. (you can create an array of controls)

Comment: VB.NET, VBA and VBScript are different languages - which language do you want?  It appears you're using VB.NET.

Comment: Per their last thread - he has to use an Array - unfortunately. The schools need to stop this horrible design!

Comment: Yes I do need to use an array.  You are correct sir.

Comment: You haven't even posted an effort to write a loop yourself. You need to at least try, and then you can ask a question here about why it's not working. If you can't even get started, ask your teacher for extra help; you've either not been paying attention in class, or they haven't yet earned their pay.

Comment: If you need an array, create an array.  Make it large enough to hold the number of values you expect to collect.  Pay attention to data types, you are reading STRINGS (ie Text) and you cannot do math on STRINGS.  Once you have the data where you want it, create a loop to do the math.  Give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what an array is.

To create an array:

```
Dim p as integer(6)
```

To put data into an array

```
p(1) = studentInfo(4)  
p(2) = studentInfo(5)  
'etc
```

To get data out of an array

```
b = p(1)
```

To loop through an array:

```
For i as Integer = 1 to 6
    total += p(i)
Next
```

Comment: For i As Integer = 1 to 6 total += p(i)
NextThis is what I was looking for, I just forgot how to set this up and that is exactly what I was looking for I'm pretty sure.  Thanks Derek

Comment: Traditionally you tick the box to say this is the correct answer :)